# Should I use Flutter state management packages for my own custom package?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-packages

I have been working on a custom multi-page Flutter package that uses the camera to take images and videos to upload on the server, I feel my code is starting to get messy as I have used methods with `SetStates` all over the place.

Should I use lightweight state management packages like Provider or it's better to keep my package less dependent on third-party state management packages?

Comment: Of course state management will make your code easier to handle

Comment: you can use PROVIDER. There are already many packages that uses provider as dependency like flutter_bloc.

Comment: In my opinion, it is better to stay less dependent, try using classes such as ChangeNotifier, and Widgets like ValueLiestenableBuilder

Comment: It is unfortunate that InheritedWidget is slightly broken enough that Riverpod had to start over with ProviderListenable using an entirely separate mechanism. Perhaps someday the flutter team will reconsider https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/107112